# Can I get different thread registers with PyDBG?

Tags: debugging, python, thread, register

I am writing a python debugger and disassembler using the PyDBG library I have the disassembler part working, but not all of the debugger. Is it possible to use it to return something similar to:

```
[*] Dumping registers for thread ID: 0x00000550
[**] EIP: 0x7c90eb94
[**] ESP: 0x0007fde0 
[**] EBP: 0x0007fdfc 
[**] EAX: 0x006ee208
[**] EBX: 0x00000000
[**] ECX: 0x0007fdd8 
[**] EDX: 0x7c90eb94 
[*] END DUMP
[*] Dumping registers for thread ID: 0x000005c0 
[**] EIP: 0x7c95077b
[**] ESP: 0x0094fff8 
[**] EBP: 0x00000000
[**] EAX: 0x00000000
[**] EBX: 0x00000001
[**] ECX: 0x00000002
[**] EDX: 0x00000003
[*] END DUMP
```

I need the register state of every thread running. There are several `thread_context` functions in PyDBG but I'm not sure how to use them to get that result. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**:>wmic process get Name,ThreadCount,ProcessId | grep fire**

```
firefox.exe                3944       49
```

**:>cat dtregs.py**

```
from pydbg import *
from pydbg.defines import *
def handler_breakpoint (pydbg):
  if pydbg.first_breakpoint:
    print "hello did i dump tid and eax for each thread ?"
    return DBG_CONTINUE
dbg = pydbg()
dbg.set_callback(EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT, handler_breakpoint)
dbg.attach(3944)
i = 0;
for thread_id in dbg.enumerate_threads():
  thread_handle  = dbg.open_thread(thread_id)
  context = dbg.get_thread_context(thread_handle)
  print "%03d TID: %08x EAX: %08x" % (i,thread_handle,context.Eax)
  i = i+1
pydbg.debug_event_loop(dbg)
dbg.detach()
```

**:>python dtregs.py**

```
000 TID: 00000690 EAX: 00000000
001 TID: 0000068c EAX: 0158c385
002 TID: 00000688 EAX: 001b4008
003 TID: 00000684 EAX: 000000e5
004 TID: 00000680 EAX: 00000000
005 TID: 0000067c EAX: 001800a3
006 TID: 00000678 EAX: 00000000
007 TID: 00000674 EAX: 000000e5
...............................
048 TID: 000005d0 EAX: 77e76c7d
049 TID: 000005cc EAX: 00000000
hello did i dump tid and eax for each thread ?
```

just to confirm if it is right to a certain degree lets attach windbg to pid
**:>cdb -p 3944**
**0:049> ~* e r eax**

```
eax=09b6a201
eax=0158c385
eax=001b4008
eax=000000e5
eax=0036ee80
eax=00000171
eax=00000000
--------------
eax=098f3ec0
eax=000000e5
eax=150ff530
eax=11d5ff00
eax=111fff00
eax=77e76c7d
eax=7ffdd000
0:049> .detach
Detached
NoTarget> q
```

Comment: For anyone who wants to view additional registers, just add:`print "%03d TID: %08x EAX: %08x" % (i,thread_handle,context.Ebx)` Notice the `Ebx`. Replace that with the appropriate register. You can print multiple registers this way.